# What is (0) means on the below Split function?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to get the last column letter.
It works correctly, but I do not understand what is `(0)` means exactly ! 
According to MS documentation and code intellisense, it should be the `Limit as integer` 
But in this case it should be inside the brackets of Split function itself like all the rest arguments

```
Dim lastCol_L As String
lastCol_L = Split(Cells(1, lastCol_n).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
```

`lastCol_n` is integer from other code
Thanks for all helpful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand what is (0) means exactly !

It's the First item of the Array. Let me show you a more orthadox way:

```
Dim lastCol_L As String
'an array of strings
Dim arr() as String
'split the cell by $ sign into an array of strings
arr = Split(Cells(1, lastCol_n).Address(True, False), "$")
'the first item of the array
lastCol_L = arr(0)
```

Comment: Haha a rhyming answer

Comment: Is that means using () to declare array is not mandatory in some cases

Comment: Yes, while VBA does support not declaring variables without `Option Explicit` you're right in this case the Array is declared under the hood - with the funky `(0)`. It's a concept of Chaining, you return the data type and continue to use functions or indexes on it. Think of JQuery or C# Fluent when I say Chaining.